# flash errors as3

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, error-handling

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at EB_fla::mc_keyboard_25/frame1()
```

On which line is this error? There does not seem to be an error pon line 25 - what specificially does this mean?

**EB_fla::mc_keyboard_25/frame1()**

Comment: It says you are trying to use a method or access a property on something that is null. Forcing the error is easy: `var mc:MovieClip = null; mc.enabled = false;`

Comment: thanks but what does the _25 refer to?

Comment: `mc_keyboard_25` is probably the instance name of some object. Are you compiling in debug mode? It should list line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some script/code in flash frames?

If so, The error is warning you there is a movieClip called mc_keyboard_25 on the frame 1 has some function or property call problem. So you should check out what happens in the frame 1 inside of this movieclip.

I hope this can help you!

Regards!